# Understanding the JVM - 2 applications in web logic server

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

I have got 2 Java applications from my vendor that will be deployed in same WebLogic server. As per their instructions, I need to create separate JVM to run the second application since it may harm first application If we run on same JVM. Here my questions are,

- Do I need to create separate JVM ?
  If Yes, How do I manage JVM's while running application ?
  If No, How does JVM take care this ?Is there any process that manages number of JVM instances or it is managed by operation system itself?
- Also at this moment I don't have any clusters in WebLogic server, will it help ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Without a great deal more context we cannot help you answer this question, this is unknown software running in an unknown environment from an unknown vendor. The best suggestion I can think of (given your question) is *follow the vendor's directions*.

Comment: Thansk Elliott, As per my understanding we are configuring JVM while installing weblogic server, How can I run application in same weblogic server with different JVM ?

Comment: Read the weblogic documentation.  You can setup separate server instances within weblogic.